# Website background picture scaling to size on independent text block

Tags: html, css

So with a website i'm working on [HERE](http://beta.morriscommunications.com.au/) when you CTRL + scroll out, the background image scales in a way that the about section text moves up in front of the picture.

I've tried things such as re-sizing and positioning elements but i am stumped on what to do or how to make the background picture scale and stay in proportion to the welcome text area.

If there are any resources out there that you know of please send a link, everything can help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

How about, in `main.css` on line 16 change:

```
height: 30%;
```

To a specific pixel height:

```
height: 275px;
```

Comment: That doesn't really work because when scrolling out it doesn't stay in proportion to the welcome text area

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#BackgroundImg {
background-image: url(yourimage.png) no-repeat center;
background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Cheers.